# How do I add a row number column in TCC Output?

Tags: xml, row-number, taleo, taleo-connect-client

How do I add a row number column in a Taleo Connect Client extract script?
I am using the below XML but I am facing issues.

```
<quer:projections alias="RCL_NP_all" xmlns:quer="http://www.taleo.com/ws/integration/query">
<quer:projection>
<quer:field path="no"/>
</quer:projection>
<quer:projection alias="rowIndex">
<quer:customValue>
<quer:expression>rowNum</quer:expression>
</quer:customValue>
</quer:projection>
</quer:projections>
```

This link I referred to: https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/18a/taleo/OTCCU/_advancedqueries.htm#OTCCUid095TG0F90HT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a row number to your export, you can use the following complex projection:

```
<quer:projection alias="RowIndex" xmlns:quer="http://www.taleo.com/ws/integration/query">
     <quer:customValue>
         <quer:expression>rowNum</quer:expression>
     </quer:customValue>
</quer:projection>
```

#### Explanation

1. Open your export in Taleo Connect Client.
2. Open the *General* tab and set the *Export mode* to "CSV-report".
3. Open the *Projections* tab.
4. Click *Add*.
5. Select *Add a complex projection* and click *OK*.
6. Under *Complex projection*, enter the following:

   ```
   <quer:projection alias="RowIndex" xmlns:quer="http://www.taleo.com/ws/integration/query">
        <quer:customValue>
            <quer:expression>rowNum</quer:expression>
        </quer:customValue>
   </quer:projection>
   ```
7. Save your changes.

#### Example

```
<quer:query productCode="RC1704" model="http://www.taleo.com/ws/tee800/2009/01" projectedClass="Candidate" locale="en" mode="CSV" csvheader="true" largegraph="true" preventDuplicates="false" xmlns:quer="http://www.taleo.com/ws/integration/query">
  <quer:subQueries/>
  <quer:projections>
    <quer:projection alias="RowIndex">
     <quer:customValue>
         <quer:expression>rowNum</quer:expression>
     </quer:customValue>
    </quer:projection>
    <quer:projection>
      <quer:field path="FirstName"/>
    </quer:projection>
    <quer:projection>
      <quer:field path="LastName"/>
    </quer:projection>
  </quer:projections>
  <quer:projectionFilterings/>
  <quer:filterings/>
  <quer:sortings/>
  <quer:sortingFilterings/>
  <quer:groupings/>
  <quer:joinings/>
</quer:query>
```

Results:

```
RowIndex,FirstName,LastName
1,John,Lee
2,Adam,Jackson
3,Jane,Doe
```

#### Notes

- If "Prevent duplicates" is enabled in advanced options, removed rows will increment the row index, even if they are not seen in the results file.

Comment: Hi Steven,
Have additional doubt in this suppose the row number needs to be added based on some logic how would that be done ? Like it should look like below example

Comment: RowNumber  Candidate Number  Salary Type        Amount

1                    123                           Annual Bonus    10000

2                    123                          Sign On Bonus   12000

Comment: 1                    132                          Annual Bonus      8000

Comment: If you are trying to reset the rowcounter for each candidate, I'm not sure how to do that. You may need to ask a separate question.